# Facing issues in __eventvalidation and __viewstate in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, eventvalidation, failed-to-load-viewstate

i have a scenario, as given below

1. once the user navigating to planning page and
2. clicks on a menu,
3. it will open the lists of recipes in week wise.
4. if the users wants to add a recipe for a particular, it has an option to click on '+', which will open a popup window which has all the recipe details available.

I have recorded the scenario using JMeter and it has the dynamic values like __VIEWSTATE and ___EVENTVALIDATION etc., and correlated  them as well.

But at the 4th step, in the jmeter instead of proper response body and the below message is displayed.
1|#||4|137|pageRedirect||%2fPerfTesting%2fError.aspx%3faspxerrorpath%3d%2fPerfTesting%2ffi-FI%2fDefault%2fKAXXILA%2fPlanning%2fPlanningMenuWeekView.aspx|

Any suggests

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan
2. Make sure that your correlation really works, i.e.

   - associated JMeter Variables are there
   - they have correct values (like you extracted the dynamic parameter fully)
   - depending on your application and extra step might be required like [URL-encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) the parameter or vice versa

   You can use [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) in order to check these variables
3. Use an external sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the requests from JMeter and the real browser, the requests must be exactly the same including:

   - URL
   - [Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)
   - Request body

   all the dynamic parameters must be properly correlated. Given you will send the same request you should get the same response